# How to revert a commit made to a particular file in SVN?

Tags: svn

Although there have been many questions already related to `svn revert`, I am not sure if this particular question has been asked before. So please read on first before you close/delete/etc. this question.

In a SVN repository a change to a file has been made as part of a larger commit. This revision, lets call it 1100, has changed the content of many files, including the file in question, lets call it `foo.php`.

As time goes by, several other changes were made to the repository, including to file `foo.php` (lets say in revisions 1200, 1300, 1400 and 1500).

At a later time it was evident, that the changes made to file `foo.php` at revision 1100 were incorrect. But ONLY revision 1100 and ONLY the specific file `foo.php`.

How can I easily revert the commit 1100, without affecting any other file, and with keeping all the intermediate changes made to file `foo.php` in revisions 1200 through 1500?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverting a commit in Subversion is applying a *reverse patch* to a file and then committing.

Suppose a file "foo.php" has a wrong change applied to it in revision `N`.  You can see what was changed by running something like

```
svn diff -c N ^/path/to/that/foo.php
```

Now you could get the reverse diff by running

```
svn diff -c -N ^/path/to/that/foo.php
```

So to revert the change do

```
svn merge -c -N ^/path/to/that/foo.php
```

while your work tree has a sensible state, then commit.

This form of merging is called "cherry-picking", and let's cite the particular bit of `svn help merge`:

> A 'reverse range' can be used to undo changes. For example, when
> source and target refer to the same branch, a previously committed
> revision can be 'undone'. In a reverse range, N is greater than M in
> '-r N:M', or the '-c' option is used with a negative number: '-c -M'
> is equivalent to '-r M:<M-1>'. Undoing changes like this is also known
> as performing a 'reverse merge'.

Comment: What does the symbol `^` stand for in this context?

Comment: It's a shortcut to the root of the repository. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html, about halfway down it's explained.

Comment: The second command does not seem to work, neither with `-M` literally, not with `M` replaced by the number of the current revision.

Comment: @Alex, sorry, my command-line `svn`-fu had just been proved to be rusty -- "the trick" is to pass a negative revision number to `-c` so I fixed the examples. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake. Your suggestion seems to work in order to solve my problem. Thanks a lot.